# I've stuffed my Banshee config, now it won't start

Tags: banshee

Not sure what I've done, but when I click the Banshee icon in the menu, the starting Banshee button appears for a few seconds in the taskbar at the bottom, then disappears.

I'm running 10.04 lucid by the way.

If I try to start it using the command line, I just get a blinking cursor.

I can start it as root, but it advises me to move my music to root's home directory, but I don't want to run it as root anyway.

I've tried re-installing, upgrading to a newer version, reverting back to an older version etc, all to no avail.  I've tried deleting all the config files etc, but nothing works.

If I log in as another user it works, so I know it's something in the config, but I just can't work out what.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: One way to solve the problem is to delete the banshee config file and folder. This would DELETE all your personal settings and playlist, restart the bansee.

Comment: If you run `banshee --debug` from the terminal, it should give more useful output, which might contain a clue about the problem.

Comment: Tried debug, and this is what it says:

Comment: geoff@Qube:~$ banshee --debug
** Running Mono with --debug   **
[1 Debug 15:03:34.257] Bus.Session.RequestName ('org.bansheeproject.Banshee') replied with InQueue
this is followed by a blinking cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is two step workouts to this...

Go to your home folder, hit <kbd>Ctrl+h</kbd> to view dotted (hidden) files.
Alternatively go to **menu >> View >> Show hidden files**

Then search for the folder **.config** open it and search for **.banshee**
Delete the folder **.banshee**

Then throw up the terminal : <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+t</kbd>
issue these commands one by one

```
sudo apt-get purge banshee
sudo apt-get remove banshee
sudo apt-get install banshee
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: this boggs me lil'bit..  clearing the folder from .config and re installing the applications always works !

Comment: It boggs me too @Z9iT I've tried all of the suggestions listed above and none of them work.  I've tried running it with the --debug option and posted the results above but so far no reply.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove an app totally, including its configuration files, here is the command that you may use in a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t):

```
sudo apt-get purge banshee
```

Then you can try reinstalling Banshee, from the Ubuntu Software Center for instance.